# Create a regex that ignores HTML comments

Tags: regex

I am looking to scan through some HTML and look for specific text (lets say "foo") but if it is in a comment I don't want to include it

So say I had some html like this:

```
<div id="foo"> Some foo here
<!-- this is a foo comment

-->
And finally some more foo
```

It would find all the foo's EXCEPT the foo comment

I've played with negative lookaheads but for the life of me cannot get it to work...

Any regex guru's out there?

I know some folks will suggest using a HTML parser but I want to stay away from that...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I recommend reading [Why you shouldn't parse HTML with regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: On a side note, why do you want to stay away from an HTML parser? It's the right tool for the job.

Comment: Basically because I'm not trying to parse HTML, I just want to identify if a specific string exists, not inside a comment. I don't care about the rest of the html, if it's formed correctly or it's contents. Seems like a perfect use of regex in one line of code - no? The fact that it is HTML is almost inconsequential. If I change the question to can I identify if foo is not between quotes does that make sense?

Comment: Definitely would be much more feasible question :) Be sure to attempt it yourself first, and if you can't solve it, include that information to demonstrate what you've tried and where you ran into problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is not recommended for this but if you want:

```
foo(?![^>]*-->)
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/cbSdIw56y3)